# How to add custom typing correctly for tests

Tags: angular, webpack, karma-runner

I wanted to define a global constant based on the webpack config.
Therefore I added the constant `DEBUG` to the DefinePlugin.

The said constant then should be used inside of some code, in my case inside of a service.

When doing `npm run build` I received an error, that the name `DEBUG` could not be found, so I added a `custom-typings.d.ts` which solved this.
But I still get the error, when running the tests.

Question is, how do I define custom typings so karma is using them as well? Or differently said, how can I make use of the `custom-typings.d.ts` when running the tests?

**./webpack.config.js**

```
    [...]
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        DEBUG: JSON.stringify(true)
    }),
    [...]
```

**./src/app/services/SomeService**

```
[...]
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
    [...]
    private shouldStart() {
        return !(DEBUG);
    }
}
```

**./src/custom-typings.d.ts**

`declare var DEBUG: boolean;`

**./src/test.ts**

```
[...]
TestBed.initTestEnvironment(
    BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
    platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);

// load all specs in ./src .
const context = (require as any).context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
context.keys().map(context);
```

**./src/tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "",
        [...]
    },
    "files": ["test.ts"],
    "include": ["**/*.spec.ts", "**/*.d.ts"]
}
```

**Error thrown when running `npm test`**

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/app/some/some.service.ts:112:14
TS2304: Cannot find name 'DEBUG'.
```

(this error occurred in the building process as well before I had the custom-typings.d.ts)

**EDIT:** Added the paths for clarification as well as some more information

Answer (score 0):

To answer for your specific project, I'd have to see where the custom-typings.d.ts file is in your project's file tree.

For a *.d.ts file to work, it needs to be located along-side your main entry point .ts file. If you use a `baseUrl` config in your tsconfig.json, it should be at the path you define there.

It should be included in your karma build automatically if the file is in the right path.

Comment: I added the infos in my question, hope that helps for getting closer to a solution :)